# I typed docker run ubuntu, now what?

Tags: docker

I know, I know, I should have typed

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

But the fact remains, a container has been created, it is there, and it is stopped. It stops as soon as it is started, so there's no way to attach or exec in it.

Is it really the case that there's is absolutely no way to change it's state so that bash is started instead ? This seems to be kind of a showstopper to me. Or maybe there's something I didn't get about the marvelous possibilities of docker that would make such a thing complicated to do ? I doubt that.

Why is it that way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind two things:

- 1st: a container is up and running as long as its main process is up and running.
- 2nd: `ubuntu` has a default command: `CMD ["/bin/bash"]`. When you use `docker run ubuntu bash`, you overwrite it to `CMD ["bash"]`. No big difference.

---

### Why `docker run ubuntu` fails:

Because `bash` simply exits. Remember, `bash` is the default command.

### Why `docker run -it ubuntu` succeeds:

Because `-t` makes `bash` keep running. From `docker run --help`:

```
-t, --tty                            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

Also, you mention:

> *But the fact remains, a container has been created, it is there, and it is stopped. It stops as soon as it is started, so there's no way to attach or exec in it.*

Containers can be better considered as processes and this is why you should see them as something ephemeral. If it happens to `run` a container with the wrong configuration (exiting right after start), remove it and spin up a new one, this time with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

when you run image like ubuntu you have to give it a command or process to keep it started. In my case when I use ubuntu image for tests (principally), I write `docker run --name myubuntu -d ubuntu:16.04 sleep 3000`

you can verify if it runing with a `docker ps`.

After this you can go inside with `docker exec -it myubuntu /bin/bash`